# pyspark - flatten nested rdd using lambda expression with map()

Tags: python, list, lambda, list-comprehension

To flatten nested lists I've always successfully used either a list comprehension, or itertools.chain.from_iterable.

Using pyspark, however, I need to flatten a list of lists (of tupples) by mapping a lambda function, and for some reason I can't 'convert' this successful list comprehension:

```
z = [[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)]]

[(j,k) for sublist in z for j,k in sublist]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)] # right answer
```

To the equivalent map / lambda equivalent:

```
list(map(lambda z: [(j,k) for sublist in z for j,k in sublist],z))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This is driving me crazy!  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't do that with `map`. You need `fold/reduce`.

Comment: @JaredSmith you *could* do it with map in totally despicable ways...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga given the fact that the OP is aware of `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, I wonder if we haven't already wound up there...

Comment: Full reveal: I'm bound to map/lambda because I'm actually trying to flatten an RDD using pyspark, and want to avoid casting the entire RDD to a list to then flatten (using, for example, itertools, reduce, etc) as it's quite large.

Comment: @pniessen so this sounds like the XY problem. Maybe you can elaborate on the above in the question...

Comment: Thanks to all for comments - I've updated question to provide more specifics on my use case, e.g. flatten a pyspark nested RDD, rather than a plain old python list. There are so many parallels between two that I thought phrasing question more generally might have been more helpful, but I think it just caused confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(z))
```

OR, you may also use `sum()` as:

```
sum(z, [])
```

However, if it is must to use  *lambda expression*, then it could be used with `reduce` as:

```
list(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, z))
```

Value returned by each of the above expression will be:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
```

Comment: Sure ... It'll just take you `O(N^2)` time ;-)

Comment: @mgilson OP already established that he/she is aware of the alternatives, but for 'certain reasons' must use HOF.

Comment: @mgilson You are right. No arguments on that.It is possibly the worst way to achieve this. But I think this is what OP wants :)

Comment: Back story - I'm bound to map/lambda because I'm actually trying to flatten an RDD of the form 

    rdd = [[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)]]

using pyspark, and want to avoid casting the entire RDD to a list to then flatten (using, for example, itertools, reduce, sum, etc) as it's quite large.

Comment: @pniessen Your understanding of map is incorrect. You should be using generator expression. Infact chain is is a iterator expression like `map` (also like `reduce`)

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but formally fulfilling the requirement `lambda` and `map`:

```
>>> res = []
>>> list(map(lambda z: res.extend(z), z))
>>> res
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
```

Comment: May the gods of LAMBDA curse you!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, this is likely as un-functional as it gets.